# Make Android Navigation Drawer Scroll-able

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-navigationview

I have a Navigation drawer with three sections, Top,Middle and Bottom I need to make middle section to be scroll-able.

[image]

Here is my current layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
<!-- begin Top Section--> 
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_black"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            />
<!--End Top Section-->    
<!-- begin Middle Section-->     
                    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_top"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:background="@color/menuColor"
                        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
                        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer_top"
                        app:itemTextColor="@color/menuTextColour" />
<!-- End Middle Section-->
<!-- begin Bottom Section-->         
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/background_black"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_group_line"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/menuTextColour">

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/menuColor_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/menuTextColour"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer_bottom" />
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
<!-- End Bottom Section-->      

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

How could I make meddle section scorll-able in my navigation view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationView gives you attr app:headerLayout for adding header for navigation.
For adding footer just wrap the desired footer view in your NavigationView,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/ll_header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_textview"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Your Header Text Here" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_footer"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" >


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_footer"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/nav_footer_textview"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Your Footer Text Here" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

for example purpose,I have used TextView.

Comment: @NeranjaGunarathne i have edited the snippet ,pls check it ,its working for me.